# Set Node.exe to use cmd.exe and not PowerShell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, node.js

When running Node.js command, it's automatically using Powershell and not cmd.exe. The `comspec` settings are set to cmd.exe. Is there any other place where I should change this?

I'm not sure if it's Windows- or Node.js-related settings (or maybe both).

Node v6.10.2, Windows 8.1 pro

If someone know Salesforce DX, this is what I'm running, the sfdx is using node, and node.exe trigger Powershell instead of cmd.exe:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias "dev-hub-org"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js itself (`node.exe`) uses neither PowerShell nor Command Prompt. (Since, it is a command-line app, however, it runs Console Host.)

Saleforce DX, however, may launch whatever it likes, be it Command Prompt or PowerShell. You have to take it up with its developers.